# MS Access - how to merge query results

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a couple of tables from which I`m trying to join the results.

The query I`m using:

```
SELECT distinct CTCtbl.nombre, CTCtbl.Apellido, CTCtbl.LimitacionB1 AS serie, CTCtbl.NumCertificadoSegTipo AS Numero_Certificado, CTCtbl.FechaExpediciónRecOfi AS Fecha_Expedicion, GradoTbl.Grado AS Grado, CTCtbl.NumGol AS Numero_Aplicacion, CTCtbl.ReciboCTC AS Numero_Recibo, Endoso1+CantBSTC+CantBSTCone AS [Colocar los códigos asignados para cada curso a endosar], CursosTBL.cod_curso AS Curso
FROM CTCtbl, GradoTbl, CursosTBL, TipoCerCTCtbl
WHERE (((IsNumeric([NumCertificadoSegTipo]))=True) AND ((CTCtbl.[TipoCertiID]) Not In (4,6,7) And (CTCtbl.[TipoCertiID]) In (1,2)) AND ((CTCtbl.[FechaExpediciónRecOfi]) Between #5/16/2016# And #5/31/2016#) AND ((CTCtbl.GradoID)=[GradoTbl].[GradoID]) AND ((CursosTBL.id)=[TipoCerCTCtbl].[CertoID]) AND ((TipoCerCTCtbl.ctcid)=[CTCtbl].[CtcID]));
```

I`m having trouble with the column:`Curso`. For each value it finds for`Curso`, it will output another row. I want it to be in one row.

Picture below shows the current output.
[image]

Tables are setup as follow:

```
TipoCerCTCtbl (ID,CTCID,CertoID)
CursosTBL (ID,COD_CURSOS,DESCR,CURSOS,PRIO)
```

Should I alter the table TipoCerCTCtbl to add CertoID_1, CertoID_2, etc? Or is there a smarter solution?

Comment: if you want to have a column for each `curso`, then you need to create as many columns for them as the maximum number of those will likely be. However workaround can be to just use your query as it is, and "pivot" it either in a report, either in another tool (e.g. in Excel using power pivot)

Comment: I tried to add multiple colums for curso, however I cant get my query to function as it should. I appended; and CursosTBL.id=TipoCerCTCtbl.CertoID_1 or  CursosTBL.id=TipoCerCTCtbl.CertoID_2 , etc. This gives me a lot of false results. How should I adjust my query to work properly?